# How to group field by id and find the sum?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the following data

```
id    starting_point      ending_point            Date
A        2525                 6565        25/05/2017  13:25:00
B        5656                 8989        25/01/2017  10:55:00
A        1234                 5656        20/05/2017  03:20:00
A        4562                 6245        01/02/2017  19:45:00
B        6496                 9999        06/12/2016  21:55:00
B        1122                 2211        20/03/2017  18:30:00
```

How to group the data by their id in the ascending order of date and find the sum of first stating point and last starting point. In this case,

Expected output is :

```
  id    starting_point      ending_point            Date           Value
A        4562                 6245        01/02/2017  19:45:00    
A        1234                 5656        20/05/2017  03:20:00
A        2525                 6565        25/05/2017  13:25:00    4532 + 6565 = 11127
B        6496                 9999        06/12/2016  21:55:00
B        1122                 2211        20/03/2017  18:30:00    6496 + 2211 = 8707
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [146]: x.groupby('id').apply(lambda df: df['starting_point'].head(1).values[0] 
                                           + df['ending_point'].tail(1).values[0])
Out[146]:
id
A    8770
B    7867
dtype: int64
```